# Ixora often called coloquially as 'Flame of the woods'. Sentence correction and formation

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

Does it correct sentence formation?

Ixora often called coloquially as 'Flame of the woods'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence needs a verb (Ixora *is* often called...).

*Called* doesn't need to be followed by *as*, although it could be replaced with *known as.*

*Colloquially* has a double 'l'.